# DATABASE - Relationship between Tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm new in databases so it's been a little bit hard to understant certain things.

My main doubt it's about one situation.

A (stupid) example:

I have one table for President and other table for Elections.

**President:**
PresidentID
Name
DateOfBirt
...

**Election:**
ElectionID
DateOfElection
...

A President can go to many Elections, as long they are from different Countries.

What's the design of new table(s) that I have to make?

Sorry if this is very simple, but I don't see how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
ElectionPresident
------------------
PresidentID <--PK, FK to President
ElectionID <-- PK, FK to Election
```

to address the country issue, you could do:

```
ElectionPresident
------------------
PresidentID <--PK, FK to President
ElectionID  <-- PK, FK to Election 
CountryID   <-- FK to Country
```

and have a unique index on `(PresidentID, CountryID)`

Comment: That doesn't address the country constraint.

Comment: So a Table ElectionPresident with only this 2 FK's and no more columns?And no PK?

Comment: @wormwood87 See my edit, There **is** a compound PK on that table. If you mean a single surrogate PK, that's your choice. If you do that, then you should put a unique index on `(PresidentID, ElectionID)`.

Comment: That's better, but you would be better off referencing the country ID on the elections table, because otherwise I can say I attended two elections in the same country but falsely supply the wrong country ID in this column. We can assume by transitivity that the country ID is a valid reference to the countries table if that constraint is on the elections table.